# install Gd extension on docker

Tags: php, docker

I triedto install gd extension on docker but it doesn't worked,I found some examples many with php-fm, but its not working with the image that I used ,this is my `dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:7.4.2-apache

RUN pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug && docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql && pecl install apcu && docker-php-ext-enable apcu \
# not yet in linux: xdebug.remote_host = host.docker.internal \n\
&& echo "\n\
xdebug.mode = debug \n\
xdebug.start_with_request = yes \n\
xdebug.client_port = 9003 \n\
xdebug.client_host = 172.18.0.1 \n\
xdebug.log = "C:\xdebug_log\xdebug.log" \n\
xdebug.idekey = VSCODE \n\
" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install libfontconfig1 libxrender1 libxext6  \
    && apt-get clean; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*

RUN cd /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/ && \
  echo 'memory_limit = -1' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-memlimit.ini

RUN docker-php-ext-install opcache && docker-php-ext-enable opcache
```

**UPDATE:**

```
I made some changes  , then  my dockerfile is 

FROM php:7.4.2-apache

RUN pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug && docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql && pecl install apcu && docker-php-ext-enable apcu \
# not yet in linux: xdebug.remote_host = host.docker.internal \n\
&& echo "\n\
xdebug.mode = debug \n\
xdebug.start_with_request = yes \n\
xdebug.client_port = 9003 \n\
xdebug.client_host = 172.18.0.1 \n\
xdebug.log = "C:\xdebug_log\xdebug.log" \n\
xdebug.idekey = VSCODE \n\
" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install libfontconfig1 libxrender1 libxext6  \
    && apt-get clean; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*

RUN cd /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/ && \
  echo 'memory_limit = -1' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-memlimit.ini

RUN docker-php-ext-install opcache && docker-php-ext-enable opcache

RUN apt-get install -y \
        libzip-dev \
        zip \
  && docker-php-ext-install zip

# GD
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
  && docker-php-ext-install -j "$(nproc)" gd

COPY 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
    
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
            libfreetype6-dev \
            libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
            libpng-dev \
        && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv \
        && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
        && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
    
    COPY 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

and I get this error:

    configure: error: unrecognized options: --with-freetype-dir, --with-jpeg-dir
    ERROR: Service 'apache_with_php' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y         libfreetype6-dev         libjpeg62-turbo-dev         libpng-dev     && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv     && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/     && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I trid to install zlib, because It warns that cannot found it , the I tri to instal zlib and gd, but I get

```
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package libzip-dev
E: Unable to locate package zip
ERROR: Service 'apache_with_php' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y         libzip-dev         zip   && docker-php-ext-install zip' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I made some changes in my dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4.2-apache

RUN pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug && docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql && pecl install apcu && docker-php-ext-enable apcu \
# not yet in linux: xdebug.remote_host = host.docker.internal \n\
&& echo "\n\
xdebug.mode = debug \n\
xdebug.start_with_request = yes \n\
xdebug.client_port = 9003 \n\
xdebug.client_host = 172.18.0.1 \n\
xdebug.log = "C:\xdebug_log\xdebug.log" \n\
xdebug.idekey = VSCODE \n\
" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install libfontconfig1 libxrender1 libxext6  \
    && apt-get clean

RUN cd /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/ && \
  echo 'memory_limit = -1' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-memlimit.ini

RUN docker-php-ext-install opcache && docker-php-ext-enable opcache

RUN apt update && apt install -y zlib1g-dev libpng-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd && docker-php-ext-enable gd

#RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*

COPY 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

now there is no error on build, but I get this message:

```
warning: gd (gd.so) is already loaded!
```

and when I check the `phpinfo()` `gd` is not on the extension list

Comment: `unrecognized options: --with-freetype-dir, --with-jpeg-dir` - sounds like you should not use them?

Comment: Does https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/912 help? Using a search machine before posting such a problem helps sometimes ;)

Comment: @NicoHaase I changed it, I searched but didn't worked, then I ask

Comment: Installing packages after you've removed all stuff from `/var/lib/apt/lists` sounds strange - why do you do this? Why not install all Debian packages in one step? Also, this is in no way related to PHP, so please remove that tag on the next edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, your dependencies should be installed in a `RUN`, if you delete `/var/lib/apt/lists`, you will have to run an `apt-get update` again and again afterwards to make sure the data is there, otherwise you will not be able to install anything via `apt-get install`.

```
FROM php:7.4.2-apache
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install libfontconfig1 libxrender1 libxext6 zlib1g-dev libpng-dev libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* 

RUN pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug && docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql && pecl install apcu && docker-php-ext-enable apcu \
# not yet in linux: xdebug.remote_host = host.docker.internal \n\
&& echo "\n\
xdebug.mode = debug \n\
xdebug.start_with_request = yes \n\
xdebug.client_port = 9003 \n\
xdebug.client_host = 172.18.0.1 \n\
xdebug.log = "C:\xdebug_log\xdebug.log" \n\
xdebug.idekey = VSCODE \n\
" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini

RUN cd /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/ && \
  echo 'memory_limit = -1' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-memlimit.ini

RUN docker-php-ext-install opcache && docker-php-ext-enable opcache \
    docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg --with-png && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

RUN /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*

COPY 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

Comment: I deleted `/var/lib/apt/lists`

Comment: I've updated my anser and hope this will bring you what you need. Please reade the docs of https://hub.docker.com/_/php to get more details how to build extensions.